# How to fit curve with asymmetric error bars?

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I got some data as a result of a series of computer simulation with possible results of 1 and 0. They have asymmetric errorbars.

I.E:

```
xdata = [...]
pdata = [...]
pdatamax = [...]
pdatamin = [...]
```

I want to fit a sigmoidal curve to my data and tried to do so using the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit1` function:

```
def sigmoid(x,x0,k):
        y = 1./(1+np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
        return y

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
```

The `curve_fit` apparently only expects the standard derivation sigma as an argument. How can I fit the curve taking in account the asymmetric error bars?

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: Do I get it right, that you basically have data with asymetric error bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using lmfit.
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/

it comes with capabilities to run least-sq fitting using scipy routines with a specified "parameters" object that allows you to specify vary/not-vary, min/max and complex relationships:

```
%pylab inline
import lmfit

def sigmoid(x,x0,k):
        y = 1./(1+np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
        return y

x = linspace(0,10,100)
x0 = 1
k = 1
y = sigmoid(x, x0, k)
noise = (np.random.rand(100) - 0.5) / 20
y_data = y + noise

def residuals(params, x, y_data):
    x0 = params['x0'].value
    k = params['k'].value
    y_calc = sigmoid(x, x0, k)
    return y_data - y_calc

parameters = lmfit.Parameters()
parameters.add("x0", value=1, vary=True, min=0.1, max=2.0)
parameters.add("k", value=1, vary=True, min=0.1, max=2.0)

result = lmfit.minimize(residuals, parameters, args=(x, y_data))
lmfit.report_fit(result.params)

plot(x, y_data)
plot(x, sigmoid(x, result.params['x0'].value, result.params['k'].value))
```

output:

```
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
[[Variables]]
    x0:   1.01570966 +/- 0.012437 (1.22%) (init= 1)
    k:    0.99250215 +/- 0.012903 (1.30%) (init= 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(x0, k)                     =  0.355
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`curve_fit()` accepts the `bounds` argument starting from SciPy 0.17.0.

Comment: the `bounds` argument is about  bounds for the fit parameters, not about error bounds.